# A jQuery Table with a column that allows tagging

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagging

Up to now I have a simple HTML table with an extra column which contains a <ul> element which is marked dropable. I have a list of elements below the table and are able to drag that tags to the specific cell to tag a displayed datarow (with ajax server communication and stuff).

Now I want a more fancy table which allows for column sorting, reordering, searching and paging and have also that simple drag 'n drop (if possible) tagging of specific rows. I'm looking at maybe jquery datatable or flextable (or similar powerful library) and add a column which allows that kind of dynamic editing.

I see at least two options: Try to implement drag'n drop inside the table to have the same as before or try to write a cell editor which uses a "tag" library (for example http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/ ) but I would need a library which lets you only choose pre-existing tags easily.

My question: Is any of this two options possible, and if, how? Or is there a more "out of the stock" option to do that?